# Traer los ids de una tabla cuando estén completos en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero traer los ids de una tabla cuando estos estén registrados en la tabla intermedia. Ejemplo:

Tengo una tabla llamada *cursos* que tienen 7 ids (cada uno pertenece a un curso), y tengo otra tabla que es *asistencia_curso* donde por id del curso y id del usuario se registra en esta tabla. Ahora lo que no sé hacer es el script: necesitaría ayuda con un script donde valide id por id que sí esté asociado a la otra tabla y en caso de que falte uno no traer nada, o sea que, si el usuario no tiene asistencia del id curso 6, no traer ni los id, 1, 2, 3, etc., solo debe de traer todos los ids cuando se cumplan todos.

Nota: los ids no son fijos, entonces no puedo usar un where in; y tampoco puedo usar un count ya que un usuario puede repetir un curso con lo cual quedan dos registros en la tabla al mismo curso.

Tabla de los cursos

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |

Tabla de asistencia

| idasistenciacurso |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Como se dan cuenta, falta el id del curso 7: quiero que la consulta no me devuelva nada ya que me falta un id, pero en caso de que sí estén todos, me devuelva

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |

De momento intenté hacerlo con un left join pero no me sirve de mucho.

```
select ac.idasistenciacurso, c.idcurso
from curso
cross join usuarios u
left join asistencia_curso ac on c.idcurso = ac.idcurso and u.idusuario = ac.idusuario
where u.usuario =291
```

resultado

| idasistenciacurso | idcurso |
| --- | --- |
| 514 | 1 |
| 520 | 2 |
| 526 | 3 |
| 533 | 4 |
| 578 | 5 |
| 35196 | 6 |
| [NULL] | 7 |

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer en 1 sola consulta:

- Para saber que cursos SI realizo el usuario, podes hacerlo así:

```sql
SELECT ac.idasistenciacurso, ac.idcurso
    FROM asistencia_curso ac
    WHERE ac.idusuario = 291;
```

- Para saber que curso NO realizo el usuario, podemos hacerlo así:

```sql
SELECT c.idcurso
FROM cursos c
    LEFT JOIN asistencia_curso ac
    ON ac.idcurso = c.idcurso
    AND ac.idusuario = 291
WHERE ac.idasistenciacurso IS NULL;
```

- Si combinamos ambas podemos obtener el resultado esperado:

```
SELECT ac.idasistenciacurso, ac.idcurso
    FROM asistencia_curso ac
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT c.idcurso
          FROM cursos c
              LEFT JOIN asistencia_curso ac
              ON ac.idcurso = c.idcurso
              AND ac.idusuario = 291
          WHERE ac.idasistenciacurso IS NULL
          LIMIT 1 -- al menos 1
        ) t
        ON 1
    WHERE ac.idusuario = 291
        AND t.idcurso IS NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/myPiJreaKXBDNkUK3eXZEh/1)</kbd>